# How to read container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total metric?

Tags: prometheus, cpu-usage

This is `container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total` metric. But I'm not sure how to read this graph ?
I can see 27 seconds increment within 08.09.45 to 08.09.52. How this is possible ?
[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should wrap this metric into [rate()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) function:

```
rate(container_cpu_cfs_throttled_seconds_total[5m])
```

It will show spikes at time ranges when there wasn't enough CPU resources for the container due to [CPU limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-cpu). The returned non-zero value shows how many additional CPU cores were needed for the container to run without CPU throttling.